# DataTables sScrollY + white-space:nowrap; broken in Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m

Tags: css, google-chrome, datatables

Upon updating to Google Chrome version `30.0.1599.69 m` today, I'm encountering a problem with `sScrollY` and `white-space:nowrap;` in jQuery DataTables. The headers are only wide enough to fit the wrapped text, not the one-lined text (Remove white-space:nowrap; and compare header widths from before and after to see what I mean).

```
.one-line{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Using a standard table, here's my init code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table").dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "100px",
    "aoColumns": [
        {'sClass': 'one-line'},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ymq6s/

Testing on Chrome `29.0.1547.66 m` works fine.

Comment: If it is a problem targeting a certain version of chrome -> chrome://feedback in your browser. Running 21.0.1180.89, ok here - never seen datatables sScrollY problems in any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome 30 has a bug. Apparently it's been fixed, and will be updated soon (hopefully?): 
[Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290399)

Comment: The bug has been fixed in my update this morning, thank you for letting me know about this!